Existence of high-weight perfect matching
I have the following problem from Korte and Vygen:

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular and $(k-1)$-edge-connected graph with an even number of vertices, and let $c\colon E(G) \to
\mathbb R_+$ be a weight function. Show that there exists a perfect matching $M$ in $G$ with $c(M) \geq \frac{1}{k}c(E(G))$.

I have solved the question for the case where there are no weights on the edges by essentially showing that there exists such a perfect matching and using Edmonds characterization of the perfect matching polytope; however I'm having trouble generalizing this. Any help would be helpful!

Try to directly proof the statement by showing that the vector with all entries $1/k$ is in the perfect matching polytope.
